# Android invalidate not calling onDraw method. setWillNotDraw(false) not working

Tags: android, conways-game-of-life

I am developing conway's game of life in android. I have created a custom view for drawing a grid and I am using it's ondraw method for rendering the grid on every cell click. Although invalidate method works for my click event and renders grid again. It doesn't work when I try to reset the grid(public void resetGrid() method). setWillNotDraw(false) is also not working.

Below are the files in mycode -

**MainActivity.java -**

```
package com.example.pavanshah.gameoflifetrial;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final PixelGridView pixelGrid = new PixelGridView(this);
    Button generateNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    Button resetGrid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);

    generateNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pixelGrid.generateNext();
        }
    });

    resetGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pixelGrid.resetGrid();
        }
    });

}

}
```

**activity_main.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.pavanshah.gameoflifetrial.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game Of Life"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    />

<com.example.pavanshah.gameoflifetrial.PixelGridView
    android:id="@+id/myGrid"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**PixelGridView.java -**

```
package com.example.pavanshah.gameoflifetrial;


public class PixelGridView extends View {

private int numColumns = 12, numRows = 12;
private int cellWidth, cellHeight;
private Paint blackPaint = new Paint();
private boolean[][] cellChecked, nextGeneration;

public PixelGridView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    calculateDimensions();
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public PixelGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    blackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
}

public void generateNext()
{
    int totalNeighbours;
    nextGeneration = new boolean[numColumns][numRows];

    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            totalNeighbours = calculateNeighbours();

            if (cellChecked[i][j] != false) {
                if ((totalNeighbours >= 2) && (totalNeighbours <= 3)) {
                    nextGeneration[i][j] = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (totalNeighbours == 3) {
                    nextGeneration[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private int calculateNeighbours()
{
        return 0;
}

public void resetGrid()
{
    Log.d("PAVAN", "Reset Grid");


    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            cellChecked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    //this.setWillNotDraw(false);
    invalidate();
}

private void calculateDimensions() {

    cellWidth = getWidth() / numColumns;
    cellHeight = getHeight() / numRows;

    cellChecked = new boolean[numColumns][numRows];

    Log.d("PAVAN", "Calculate dimentions");

    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    calculateDimensions();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    Log.d("PAVAN", "On Draw");

    if (numColumns == 0 || numRows == 0) {
        return;
    }

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int circX = width/2;
    int circY = height/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            if (cellChecked[i][j]) {


                canvas.drawRect(i * cellWidth, j * cellHeight,
                        (i + 1) * cellWidth, (j + 1) * cellHeight,
                        blackPaint);

                //canvas.drawCircle(circX * i, circY * j, circX, blackPaint );
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < numColumns; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(i * cellWidth, 0, i * cellWidth, height, blackPaint);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i * cellHeight, width, i * cellHeight, blackPaint);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        int column = (int)(event.getX() / cellWidth);
        int row = (int)(event.getY() / cellHeight);

        cellChecked[column][row] = !cellChecked[column][row];
        invalidate();
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: `pixelGrid` in your code isn't referring to the one on-screen. You've created a new, separate instance in `onCreate()` that's not being used anywhere. Instead of creating one with `new` there, use `findViewById()` to get the one from the layout -- `pixelGrid = (PixelGridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);`.

Comment: Yep. That worked. Thanks a lot.